# Handling Caching and Undefined Variables after Rebuild in Nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, caching, next.js13, browser-cache

I have a problem in Nextjs, so when I keep a page open and do a rebuild, then I go back to that page and click any of the links it shows an error of `undefined` variables. But if I reload the page it's fine.

So I checked the network tab in chrome developer tools, I noticed that when I click a link after a rebuild, it opens a JSON file but the response is still `200` even the file doesn't exist anymore due to the rebuild. So what happens, that JSON file returns an empty response which caused the `undefined` issue.

[image]

So I downgraded Nextjs to the last version it was working for us which is `13.4.8` to see how it works. So I clicked any of the links right after the rebuild and I see the JSON files are now returning `404` which is correct since they are now removed due to the rebuild.

[image]

I think this could be a client side caching issue, since I've heard a lot of it but there were no solutions.

How can address this issue?

**Specs:**

```
Nextjs: 14.1.0
Node: v19.9.0
```

**Things I've tried:**

```
1. cacheMaxMemorySize: 0, // disable default in-memory caching
2. { cache: 'no-store', next: { revalidate: 0 } } // set fetch not to cache
3. prefetch={false} // disable prefetching in Links
```

But no luck, I'm still having the issue.

**My current solutions:**

1. Force old assets to return `404` via Nginx, but I have to add the
   assets to the rule on every build.
2. Force reload the page when it returned an `undefined` error using the
   ErrorBoundary.
3. Revert to old version which is Nextjs `13.4.8`.

I'm hesitant to select any of these options, but if there's no other solutions I may have to pick one.